# how to split up a large text file (one long string) into 50kb text files

Tags: python

i have a file "text.txt" that is 1.1MB right now. I want to split it up into 50kb text files. 
I would use a loop if I could readlines() the file, but since it's one long string, I'm not sure i could do that.

Comment: Use [`seek()` and `read()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Read a file in chunks, like done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

Comment: another option is found in [break a text file into smaller chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761016/break-a-text-file-into-smaller-chunks-in-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file, set up a byte `range` to iterate through, then [`seek()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to that location, `read()` in the content, and, if there was content, write it to a new file. If there's no content, `break` out of the loop.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for place in range(0, int(2e6), 50000):
        f.seek(place)
        content = f.read(50000)
        if content:
            with open('myfile{}.txt'.format(place), 'w') as o:
                o.write(content)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: 2e6 is two million in scientific notation. In Python, that produces a float, hence the `int()` call. It's longer and a tiny bit slower than `2000000`, but more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split command.
For ex,:-

```
split -b 50k text.txt.
```

If you want to do this from python, you could use subprocess.check_call()